# Comments send AJAX Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, ajax

Please help me to find the problem. I get Unexpected identifier when try to to use ajax for sending comments
Code:

```
    function funcSuccess (data) {
    $("#comment_ajax").text(data);
}
function funcBefore (){
    $("#comment_ajax").text("Loading comment...");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#make_comment").bind("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            let post = $("#c_post_id").val();
            let user = $("#c_user_id").val();
            let text = $("#c_text").val();
            url: "write_comment.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {c_post_id: post, c_user_id:user, c_text:text},
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: funcBefore,
            success: funcSuccess
        });
    });
});
```

It appears on the line with line "let post = $("#c_post_id").val();" What have I made wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this, replace your `=` with `:` and replace `;` with `,` in your ajax call.

```
function funcSuccess (data) {
    $("#comment_ajax").text(data);
}

function funcBefore (){
    $("#comment_ajax").text("Loading comment...");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#make_comment").bind("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            post: $("#c_post_id").val(),
            user: $("#c_user_id").val(),
            text: $("#c_text").val(),
            url: "write_comment.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {c_post_id: post, c_user_id:user, c_text:text},
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: funcBefore,
            success: funcSuccess
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you. now same code new issue: 
post.php?id=4:861 Uncaught ReferenceError: post is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (post.php?id=4:861)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)